# Cannot render error page for request [/file/download/e0ad85] and exception [] as the response has already been committed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

## Background:

I had downloaded a file that is 158MB in size. The file was successfully downloaded, but an exception was thrown.

## Exception:

Cannot render error page for request [/file/download/e0ad85] and exception [] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.

## Source Code

### Controller

```
@Api(tags = "file management api")
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/file")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FileManagerController {
    @ApiOperation(value = "File Download【F】")
    @GetMapping("/download/{fileId}")
    public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         @PathVariable @ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) String fileId) {
        portalManagementFileService.download(request, response, fileId);
    }
}
```

### Service

```
public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String fileId) {
        PoCommonFileManagementBo file = mapper.select(fileId);
        String serverFileName = file.getFileId().concat(".").concat(file.getFileType());
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;fileName*=utf-8'zh_cn'" + URLEncoder.encode(file.getFileName(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new BusinessException(CommonBusinessCodeEnum.COMMON_FILE_ENCODING_ERROR);
        }

        SftpUtil ftpUtil = new SftpUtil(host, port);
        try (InputStream in = ftpUtil.downloadFile(file.getFilePath(), serverFileName)) {
            OutputStream out;
            if (in != null) {
                out = response.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int n;
                while (-1 != (n = in.read(buffer))) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (ClientAbortException ignore) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BusinessException(CommonBusinessCodeEnum.COMMON_DOWNLOAD_FAIL, e);
        } finally {
            ftpUtil.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

why?  how to fix it ?

Successfully download the file without triggering an exception.

Comment: The error you are getting indicates that an exception was thrown *after* you already started writing the response. Because of the way HTTP responses work, that means the HTTP status code and headers have already been sent to the client. You haven't posted what that exception is, so we can't help you there.